# How can we use properties file in js file

Tags: javascript, java

I wanted to use properties file in my js file i don't know how to do that
This is my js file code

```
document.getElementById("Expedite").innerHTML = "Quickship Expedite : " + qsExpedPer
                                                + "%";
```

in place of innerHTML= "here" i want my properties file text how can i do this this is there any other method to do that
What i am doing here is i want to change this Quickship Expedite in 9 languages i have different properties file for that but i dont know hoe to use properties file in js.
someone please help.

Comment: what do you mean by properties file, give us an example?

Comment: The properties object contains key and value pair both as a string.It can be used to get property value based on the property key. The Properties class provides methods to get data from the properties file and store data into the properties file. Moreover, it can be used to get the properties of a system. For eg
db.properties
user=system  
password=oracle  
System.out.println(p.getProperty("user"));  
    System.out.println(p.getProperty("password"));

Comment: So you need a hashmap that read a file. Then use this hashmap to get property from key. Am i right?

Comment: yes that's what i want

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to use an object as a Map to contain your key value by language. Then you create a function to get the language value from it as follow:

```
/*Populate your hasmap*/
var languageMap={};


//for En language
languageMap["EN"] = {};
languageMap["EN"]["user"] = "User";
languageMap["EN"]["name"] = "Name";

//for FR language
languageMap["FR"] = {};
languageMap["FR"]["user"] = "Utilisateur";
languageMap["FR"]["name"] = "Nom";


//then you create a function to get the translation
function GetTransaltion(key, language){
    var hasLanguage = Object.keys(languageMap).includes(language);
    if(!hasLanguage){
        console.warn("The language " + language + " is not available");
        return key;
    }
    var haskey = Object.keys(languageMap[language]).includes(key);
    if(!haskey){
        console.warn("The key " + key + " is not available in language " + language);
        return key;
    }
    return languageMap[language][key];
}


//so when you get info from EN language of User you have 
GetTransaltion("user", "EN"); 

//so when you get info from FR language of User you have 
GetTransaltion("user", "FR");
```